# Segmentation fault after resizing dynamic array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays

I am getting a Segmentation fault with the following code and I really can't figure out where the problem is. The program is supposed to hold a dynamic array of unsigned integers which gets resized in the function setBreakPoint. The Segmentation fault happens during the assignment of the second element of the array (the first one works without problems).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void setBreakPoint(unsigned int **break_points, unsigned int *number_of_break_points, unsigned int new_break_point)
{
  unsigned int *buffer;
  if(new_break_point > 0)
  {
    buffer = realloc(*break_points, ++(*number_of_break_points) * sizeof(unsigned int) );
    if(buffer != NULL)
    {
      *break_points = buffer;
      *break_points[(*number_of_break_points) - 1] = new_break_point;
    }
  }
  return;
}

int main(void)
{
  unsigned int *break_points = NULL;
  unsigned int number_of_break_points = 0;

  setBreakPoint(&break_points, &number_of_break_points, 10);
  setBreakPoint(&break_points, &number_of_break_points, 5);

  free(break_points);
  return 0;
}
```

Here the output from valgrind. In total there are 12 bytes allocated, which seems quite legit (4 byte at the first function call and 8 at the second). As far as I can tell there appears to be an assignment to the NULL pointer, but I don't understand why.

```
==8695== Invalid write of size 4
==8695==    at 0x4005BA: setBreakPoint (in /break_points)
==8695==    by 0x400605: main (in /break_points)
==8695==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==8695==  
==8695== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8695==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==8695==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 12 bytes allocated
==8695== 
==8695== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8695==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8695==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8695==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8695==    still reachable: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==8695==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Comment: Assigning the result of `realloc()` to the first argument you call it with is always an error.  Don't do that, because it makes it impossible to avoid resource leaks if an error occurs.

Comment: @Alexguitar, Why will it always be true?

Comment: @Alexguitar: The call in the main function here is just an example. It's supposed to be called elsewhere too, where new_break_point does not need to be > 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this expression:

```
*break_points[(*number_of_break_points) - 1]
```

The index operator `[]` has higher precedence than the pointer reference opeator `*` so your code parses wrong. It should be:

```
(*break_points)[(*number_of_break_points) - 1]
```

Curiously, you added the parentheses to `(*number_of_break_points)`, where they are not needed.

The funny thing is that since you are using a pointer-to-pointer, both interpretations `*(p[i])` and ``(*p)[i]`are valid. Also, when the index value is`0` the resulting value is the same, that's why the first time it works but the second fails.

PS: Note that you have another suble bug: if `realloc` fails you are incrementing the counter anyway. It would be simpler something like:

```
    buffer = realloc(*break_points, (*number_of_break_points) * sizeof(unsigned int) );
    if(buffer != NULL)
    {
      *break_points = buffer;
      buffer[(*number_of_break_points)++] = new_break_point;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code `*break_points[(*number_of_break_points) - 1]` doesn't work like you expect. With the operator precedence we have in C this evaluates to `* (break_points[..])`. You should write `(*break_points)[..].